# Encryption arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, encryption

I am having trouble with this encryption function in C. char data[] holds 4 characters (i.e. Byte) that I am trying to encrypt using cipherMap[] which is found using a random number generator. Basically, nonsense[] is my encrypted array and it's index is equal to cipherMap's value...given this, I am not sure how to set the encrypted value to the byte of that particular spot from the original char data[].

I know this question may be confusing or vague but that's because I am confused...and very new at such low-level programming. Here is my code:

```
int encrypt (char data[]) // plain text in char
{
  int nonsense[28]; // cipher text
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 28; i++)
  {
    nonsense[cipherMap[i]] = data[i / 7] & (1 << (i % 7));
    printf("%d", nonsense[cipherMap[i]]);
  }
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with the fact that you regard C as a low-level programming language (which it may or may not be). From what I can tell, your question is much more of an algorithmic kind, but I don't understand what it actually is.

Comment: I've simplified your code, but the algorithm is still identical. You need to take another stab at wording your question.

Comment: If I understand the code correctly, you're putting 1 bit from the `data` in each location in the nonsense array.  The only requirement here is that the `cipherMap` has 28 unique values ranging from 0 to 27. Is that what you need help with, or are you looking for a better way to extract the bits from the `data`?

Comment: Yes, that is what I need help with! But I guess I am also not sure if the way I am trying to do the bit manipulation is right or not...

Comment: I need whatever the output is to be just 1's and 0's and right now I am getting other numbers as well...that's why I am assuming that my bit manipulation must be incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the expression `data[i / 7] & (1 << (i % 7))` yields a single bit, but leaves that bit at it's original location.  The result of the expression will be a power of two (1, 2, 4, etc).  Here's a different way to extract the bits.

```
void encrypt (char data[]) // plain text in char
{
    int nonsense[28]; // cipher text
    int i, mask, index;

    index = 0;
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ )
    {
        for ( mask = 1; mask < 128; mask <<= 1 )
        {
            if ( data[i] & mask )
                nonsense[cipherMap[index]] = 1;
            else
                nonsense[cipherMap[index]] = 0;
            index++;
        }
    }
}
```

In the code above, `i` is the array index into the plain text, and `mask` is a one-bit value that's used to check bits in the `data`.  Mask starts with a value of 1 (LSB first) and is shifted left by 1 bit each time through the loop.  When `mask` reaches the MSB, it will have a value of 128, which terminates the inner loop and allows the outer loop to move on to the next input byte. Only the seven least significant bits of each byte are encoded.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I am not sure it is doing exactly what I need...I need nonsense[28] to be: 0101101111011101011000100010 but when I print the result with that code I get: 01000010100111100010111010100110

This is given that cipherMap[28] (aka f(i)) is: 25, 11, 24, 0, 19, 2, 7, 15, 27, 14, 17, 22, 13, 26, 20, 16, 8, 10, 18, 4, 12, 9, 23, 3, 5, 21, 6, 1

And my plain text (aka data[4]) is Byte

Comment: @user3366369 I somehow missed the fact that you were only encoding 7 bits per byte.

Comment: That makes nonsense[] equal to the binary version of data[] but i need nonsense[] to be the encrypted version of that using my cipherMap[]...thanks so much for your help and I'm sorry that my questions are unclear

Comment: @user3366369 I admit that previous code that I posted wasn't tested.  This time I actually tested the code based on the information in your comment. Using the `cipherMap` that you specified, the code generated the desired output.  `for ( i = 0; i < 28; i++ ) printf( "%d", nonsense[i] );` yields 0101101111011101011000100010